# UI picker as a lookup

Tags: iphone, picker

I am trying to use a UI picker as a lookup.  There is a textField called Author.  user types there but he or she should have an option to do a lookup.  So I put a button next to the textfield.  User clicks the button I want the uipicker to appear with the list of items.  I have been able to do this.  I created a picker and populated.  User clicks on the button and I popup the picker and change the inputview of the textbox to the picker.  Picker shows up.  Then when user selects from picker or clicks elsewhere I set the inputview to nil and picker to hidden.
It all works well but then when I leave the view to go back to the previous view the picker appears and then dissapears. Am I doing this wrong?  Should I create a separate view and place the picker there or do this differently?  I am relatively new to IPHONE development.  Is there a sample someplace in the internet that one of you guys will know?

Thanks a million.
Saro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need this link to create [UIPickerView](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/UIPickerView/UIPickerViewExample.html)

Than set your picker popup code on button click, 
And one thing in mind check it when view disappear and didUnload is there pickerView displaying ?

Set one breakpoint and change the code according to your requirement..
May be this one help you [This LInk](http://www.wetware.co.nz/blog/2009/02/how-to-popup-a-uipickerview-from-the-bottom-of-a-uiscrollview-in-response-to-uitextfield-selection/)

Comment: The second link was fantastic!  Thanks for your help! It worked.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

You can always create a separate view with UIPickerView, that always easy to deal with and declare view,picker as iVars.Whenever you want to show the picker view, just add the view as `subView` and when you dont want to show it, remove the view by calling `removeFromSuperview`.

hope this helps!!